# content-class on v-dialog not showing own styling

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a simple dialog with a content-class.

```
<v-dialog content-class="foo" v-model="showDialogForProduct">
```

If I make some styling or wants to change som default dialog styling it's not showing. In my css i have:

```
.foo {
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Or if I want's to change some existing dialog css:

```
.foo .v-dialog{
  margin: 0px;
}

.foo .v-dialog:not(.v-dialog--fullscreen) {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Is there a way to change the styling or is there something wrong with the content-class?

Comment: The styling should be `.foo.v-dialog` not `.foo .v-dialog`

Comment: Still not working :-S

Comment: Try adding `margin: 0px; !important` and `max-height: 100%; !important`

Comment: I have tried and diden't work. This is wiered :-S

Comment: Alright, so either have you have to post screenshots about what is going on, or try setting up a codesandbox with the issue, it works fine when i tried in my own project.

Comment: why not just `class=...`? can you provide a [mcve] so that we can see if the css is even in the right spot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using single-file components (i.e. `App.vue`, etc), and you define your `foo` CSS class in the style tag of the component, **the styles cannot be scoped.**

This is because the dialog is removed from the component's DOM and inserted just under the `v-app` component at the top-level of the application. If you need to style a dialog, declare the CSS classes in a global style sheet or in a component's non-scoped `<style>` tag.

An alternative is to use `v-dialog`'s `attach` prop to keep the dialog DOM inside the component. You can see details of the `attach` prop [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs).

Comment: Bingo! I wasen't aware of the scope, and by removing that it's working. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The v-dialog gets removed form the DOM hence we need to make a global css file, so whenever the v-dialog is called back in DOM those styles are applied.

1) Make a css file say `global.css` in `assets` folder under `public`.

2) define your styles in the `global.css` file:

```
   .v-dialog{
        border: 1px solid gold;
    }
```

3) Link the file in index.html,

```
<link re="stylesheet" href="assets//global.css"
```

This should work fine.