# ::v-deep is not working with v-dialog content-class (scoped scss)

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to style content of the Vuetify dialog component. I use content-class prop and scoped styles to do that. What is the difference between the styles below? How can i make scss version work? [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-forked-ui804u?file=/src/App.vue).

```
<style lang="css" scoped>
>>> .dialog-content {
  outline: 5px solid black;
}
</style>
```

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
::v-deep .dialog-content {
  outline: 5px solid black;
}
</style>
```

```
<template>
  // ....
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" content-class="dialog-content">
      // ....
    </v-dialog>
  // ....
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59768842/content-class-on-v-dialog-not-showing-own-styling), styles cannot be scoped because "the dialog is removed from the component's DOM and inserted just under the v-app component at the top-level of the application"

try:

```
  <style lang="scss">
  .dialog-content {
      outline: 5px solid black;
  } 
  </style>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your reply. What i don't understand is that why it works with `lang="css"` and `>>>` while it is not working with scss and v-deep. It is a bit confusing